# Python Socket programming chat program client server

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I have written some code in attempt to make a simple but effective python chat program that uses a server client system, I need help on making my program continuously sending messages between two clients without the , and I need help incorporating a file handling feature to save the chat history the two clients make please I need some help, any help is appreciated thank you, please note Im new to python

```
  #server
    #server #final version
    import socket
    import sys
    print("\nServer")
    print()
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 4000))
    print("Waiting for connection: ")
    s.listen(10)
    conn, addr = s.accept()   
    print("Waiting for Client")
    print ("Connection from: ", addr)
    print("")


    while 10:
        username = conn.recv(1024).decode()
        password = conn.recv(1024).decode()
        print("Usernmae: ", username)
        print(" the word 'NTU' to join the chat room",password)
        if password == "ntu":
            conn.sendall(b"Logged In")
            input()
        else:
            conn.sendall(b"Failed")
            input()
        message = input(str("....."))
        message = message.encode()
        conn.send(message)
        print("Message sent..")
        recv_message = conn.recv(1024)
        print("Client  : ", recv_message.decode())


    #client

    #client #final version
    import socket
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 4000))
    print("\nClient")
    username = input("enter username: ")
    print("Your username is",username)
    s.sendall(username.encode())
    password = input("password: ")
    print("Your password is",password)
    s.sendall(password.encode())

    while 10:
        message = s.recv(1024)
        message = message.decode()
        print("Server: ", message)
        new_message = input(str(">>"))
        new_message = new_message.encode()
        s.send(new_message)
        message = s.recv(1024)
        message = message.decode()
        print("Server: ", message)
```

Comment: Welcome @Cog_Eman. Your question is asking more for general advice. This link explains how to best ask for help https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. While you have a nice sample it is unclear the exact step you are stuck on.

Comment: `socket` is low-level object and it can be painful to create something useful. For example: server doesn't know how many data is send by client. There can be delay on network and server can get part of login or password but it will not know it - so it will use this part as full login or password. You would have to send size at start or use some char to recognize end of data - it can be enter (new line).

Comment: Second: if client has to send and receive at the same time then it will have to do it in separated threads because `recv` can block code and then it can't send.. Or you may try to use `select.select()` to check if there are data in socket before you read it.

Comment: Third: if server has to handle more clients then every client will have to run in separated thread or you will have to use other method to run many elements in the same time.